# GridBagLayout in JAVA

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, gridbaglayout

I want to display image, JLabel, and JTextField using `GridBagLayout`.

The image should looked like this

[image]

This is what I have tried, but the JTextField display below images, not besides

```
   JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
   gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

   for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++) {
        Image image = ImageIO.read(file[i]);
        Image imageScaled = image.getScaledInstance(80, 95, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(imageScaled);
        foodLabel[i] = new JLabel(imageIcon);
        qtyField[i] = new JTextField(3);
    }

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            gbc.gridy += 2;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
        }
        panel.add(foodLabel[i], gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add(qtyField[i], gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.gridy--;
        tabbedPane.addTab(text, panel);
    }
```

Comment: What is on your picture the JTextField? The blue boxes?

Comment: @FlorianS. Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding and subtracting the value of `gridy` wrong. To adjust the code to `qtyField` be on the right side of `foodLabel`, simply remove those `gbc.gridy` and add a `gbc.gridx ++` after `panel.add(foodLabel[i], gbc)`.

Now, it won't be as your image (at least I think it wouldn't unless you properly setup the `foodLabel`, and even if you do, align properly will be a little to much work), to do so you can create a new array of `JLabel` (`foodImage`), the same size of `foodLabel`, where you can show only the images. Then your code will be almost right, only move some lines and add the `foodImage`. I wrote and here it is:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
// Just to give a space between the components
gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++) {
    Image image = ImageIO.read(file[i]);
    Image imageScaled = image.getScaledInstance(80, 95, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(imageScaled);
    foodImage[i] = new JLabel(imageIcon);
    foodLabel[i] = new JLabel("Label");
    qtyField[i] = new JTextField(3);
}

gbc.gridx = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        gbc.gridy += 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
    }

    // Add the image
    panel.add(foodImage[i], gbc);
    // Below the image
    gbc.gridy++;
    // Add the label
    panel.add(foodLabel[i], gbc);
    // Go back up
    gbc.gridy--;
    // Next column
    gbc.gridx++;
    // Add the textfield
    panel.add(qtyField[i], gbc);
    // Next column
    gbc.gridx++;
    tabbedPane.addTab(text, panel);
}
```

[I ran this code, and should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsPws.jpg)

Comment: How to increase the width of the JTextField?

Comment: You must create a new Dimension instance and use it in `jTextField.setPreferredSize(/*dimension instance*/)`. You also can use `setSize()`, `setMaximumSize()` or `setMinimunSize()` according you necessities. Check out the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) and the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html), both by Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the for loop like this

```
 // initialize gridy with -2 because when i == 0 you increase it by 2 in the for loop
 gbc.gridy = -2;
 gbc.gridx = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++) {
     if (i % 3 == 0) {
         gbc.gridy += 2;
         gbc.gridx = 0;
     }
     panel.add(foodLabel[i], gbc);
     gbc.gridx++;
     panel.add(qtyField[i], gbc);
     gbc.gridx++;

     // do you really whant to do this within the loop? I guess it should be outside...
     // tabbedPane.addTab(text, panel);
 }
 tabbedPane.addTab(text, panel);
```

... and one last question: Why do you increase gridy by 2? Shouldn't it be enough to increase it by 1?